# First time hit, with spinach? A little bit?

Tags: knowledge, video-games

This blockbuster game was devised around the year 1980 by a person, that had never before developed a video game.

Concerning the species, that makes the protagonist, the game's title is misleading.

It is unknown if the main character likes spinach, against the original planning of the developers.

What is the name of the video game?

Comment: When you say "devised", do you mean that development started in 1980, or it was released in 1980?

Comment: Development/invention started around 1980.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the game may be

> Donkey Kong

although there is one thing that doesn't seem quite right if so.

*This blockbuster game was devised around the year 1980*

> Released in 1981.

*by a person, that had never before developed a video game.*

> Shigeru Miyamoto ... but he had developed, or at least worked on, one game before Donkey Kong. It was called "Radar Scope" and it was commercially unsuccessful.

*Concerning the species, that makes the protagonist, the game's title is misleading.*

> No one involved is a donkey.

*It is unknown if the main character likes spinach, against the original planning of the developers.*

> Donkey Kong was originally conceived as a sort of parallel to Popeye: (Mario, girl, gorilla) : (Popeye, Olive Oyl, Bluto).

Comment: Correct answer. Since the game was basically completely converted by him, I think it counts as his first.